# Replacing special char(non printable char) in json string with space in java

Tags: java, json, regex

Trying to replace the special char(non printable char) in json-string with space. its not getting replace. But same regex is replacing in normal java string.

```java
String regex = "[\\x00-\\x1F]+";
```

**With String**

```java
String text  = "To test\tthe\tspecial char\tin text and \rtab\t\n \t Check the interest";
text = text.replaceAll(regex, " ");
```

Output:

```
To test the special char in text and  tab    Check the interest
```

**With JsonString (not working)**

```java
String text = "{\"notes\":\"To test\\tthe\\tissues\\tin text and \\rtab\\t\\n \\tCheck the interest\"}";
text = text.replaceAll(regex, " ");
```

Ouput:

```
{"note_to_regulator":"To test\tthe\tissues\tin text and \rtab\t\n \tCheck the interest"}
```

In json string this regex is not working. I guess this is due to "\" escape char in the json string But not sure. 
Please let me know the changes required in this regex to work correctly in json string also.

Comment: You don't have a tab character in the second case but rather two separate characters, a backslash followed by a `t`, which is different

Comment: yes. Actually it is \t but since it is json string its automatically adding double slash "\\t"  to escape the special char in string So here Im not able to remove the special char(\t) with regex.

Comment: No! Without getting too philosophical, it's only JSON if it is being interpreted as a JSON string when you actually parse it. Right now it's just a string that happens to start end end with { and } against which you are running a regex function. And this particular string does not contain a tab character. Now it may be that if you parse it as a JSON string the resulting object will contain a tab character, but that is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\\\[lnrt]", " ").replace("\\\\", "\\");
```

A "...\..." is a string with a backslash your string actually does not contain control characters, but representations of them.

The backslash escape in *regex*, like `\d` for *digit* must be written as `"\\d"` and the backslash itself is then escaped in regex as `"\\\\"` : a String with two backslashes.

The first regex `replaceAll` will take care of form-feed, line-feed, carriage-return and tab.
The second normal string replace will replace two backslashes with one.
It would be amusing to write this with a `replaceAll`, actually doubling the number of backslashes.

Comment: Issue is due to escape char while converting the json object into string. so added below line to remove the escape-char and applied the regex,                                                               StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(text).replaceAll(regex, " ") now its working

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the compiler is taking the actual string you provided which does not have a tab character in it, but the literal `\t` characters. If you want a tab embedded in the json string you don't need to escape the slash. That will put a real tab character in the string. If a JSON string comes in with a `\t` those are literal characters not the tab. You would need to handle the `\t` as the characters rather than looking for the tab character.